# Save multiple fields in DB

Tags: joomla-3.x, database, form, custom-component

Please help advice. How to save multiple Fields in the database. I have a form with X number of fields. Fields added using JQuery

```
<input type="text" value="" name="jform[phone]">
<input type="text" value="" name="jform[phone]">
<input type="text" value="" name="jform[phone]">
```

In models I get $data['phone'], but I can not save it in the database.
What is the best way to save multiple Fields in the database.

Comment: This question is too light on details and effort.  Please improve this question.  I would like to tell you to add a pair of square brackets to the name value (`jform[phone][]`) but then that would only be half of the job.  We don't know anything about your database table or how you wish to store the data.  You haven't shown any coding attempt at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try serializing the array before saving it to the database, and then, when you need it, you can unserialize it (you can do this using the `serialize`, `unserialize` functions).

You can also save the array as json (which is a better option) using the `json_encode` PHP function and then, when you want to retrieve it from the database, then you can use `json_decode`.